# changes inside git submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

It's possible this has been asked before, but it's difficult to tell because submodules seem to cause lots of problems. Here's what I'm doing.

```
# cd to parent repo
git submodule add git://example.com/myrepo
cd myrepo
# make some changes
git commit -am "made changes"
cd ..
git commit -am "modified submodule"
git clone --recursive . <path to cloned repo>
```

When I do this I get errors

> fatal: reference is not a tree: 96fa64c0dd64684f86d17841f7c515446885eb33

followed by

> Unable to checkout '96fa64c0dd64684f86d17841f7c515446885eb33' in submodule path 'myrepo'

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to add a submodule, then make some changes to it, and then clone the entire parent source tree (including submodule) to a new repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call

```
git submodule init
```

after you add the submodule.  `git submodule add` clones the repository and adds entries to .gitmodules.  `git submodule init` initializes the submodules and copies the entries in .gitmodules to .git/config

## EDIT

I suspect that you have missed some important step in using submodules.  Here are the steps that I use to deal with submodules.

First clone the parent repo if applicable

```
git clone git@github.com:test/test.git
```

Change to the cloned directory and add your submodule

```
#change to the parent repo directory
cd test

#add the submodule to test/submodules/mysubmodule
git add submodule git@github.com/test/mysubmodule.git submodules/mysubmodule
```

Initialize all submodules and update all submodules including nested ones

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Add all your changes and commit and push to remotes if applicable

```
git add .
git commit
```

This last part is really important as the repo does not really know about your submodule until you commit the changes.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I cloned the repo I wanted as a submodule first as a separate source tree using git clone. Then I made the necessary changes. Then I used git submodule add on the path to my local copy of the repo I wanted.

Comment: Not sure why you had to do that.  I use submodules on a daily basis - even submodules within submodules - and I have never had to separately clone one of them.  I am going to edit my answer with steps to using submodules that should work for you.